# Problem with smart contract's constructor instantiating another smart contract

Tags: remix, contract-deployment, contract-debugging

I have the following two smart contracts in the same ".sol" file: Credentials and Proposals.
Every Proposals smart contract should refer to a single Credentials smart contract, in order to do that, when Proposals is created (constructor method) it instatiates a Credentials smart contracts as you can see below.

**Credentials.sol**:

```
contract Credentials {

    uint256 _numberOfProviders;
    mapping(address => bool) public _owners;
    uint256 _numberOfOwners;

    constructor(address[] memory owners) payable{
        _owners[msg.sender] = true;
        _numberOfOwners = 1;
        for (uint i=0; i<owners.length; i++) {
            if(false == _owners[owners[i]]){
                _owners[owners[i]] = true;
                _numberOfOwners += 1;
            }
            
        }
        _numberOfProviders = 0;
    }
}
```

**Proposals.sol**:

```
contract Proposals {

    Credentials  _credentialsContract;
    address payable _chairperson;
    
    constructor() payable{
        _chairperson = payable(msg.sender);
        address[] memory listOfOwners;
        listOfOwners[0] = msg.sender;
        _credentialsContract = new Credentials(listOfOwners);
    }
}
```

In Remix the compiler works but when I try to deploy Proposals I get the following error which I do not understand:

**creation of Proposals errored: VM error: revert. revert The transaction has been reverted to the initial state. Note: The called function should be payable if you send value and the value you send should be less than your current balance. Debug the transaction to get more information.**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try this:

```
// SPDX-License-Identifier: GPL-3.0

pragma solidity >=0.7.0 <0.9.0;
contract Credentials {

    uint256 _numberOfProviders;
    mapping(address => bool) public _owners;
    uint256 _numberOfOwners;

    constructor(address[] memory owners) payable{
        _owners[msg.sender] = true;
        _numberOfOwners = 1;
        for (uint i=0; i<owners.length; i++) {
            if(false == _owners[owners[i]]){
                _owners[owners[i]] = true;
                _numberOfOwners += 1;
            }
            
        }
        _numberOfProviders = 0;
    }
}

contract Proposals{

    Credentials  _credentialsContract;
    address payable _chairperson;
    address[] listOfOwners;
    constructor() payable{
        _chairperson = payable(msg.sender);
        listOfOwners.push(address(msg.sender));
        _credentialsContract = new Credentials(listOfOwners);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your reply @DharmveersinhJadeja, nevertheless isn't more expensive (from the GAS point of view) to execute smart contracts where data is stored as properties? wouldn't it be better to somehow save the "listOfOwner" as a "memory" variable inside the constructor method?